# mongoose: Can't remove item from an array

Tags: mongoose

This is my code:

```
function remove(guild, u) {
 return db.updateOne({ guild }, {
  $pull: { "feeds": { "user": { "screen_name": u } } }
 })
}
```

When I run `remove("718471604291764295", "twitter")` it doesn't remove. My schema is:

```
{
    guild: String,
    feeds: [{
        channel: String,
        webhook: {
            id: String,
            token: String,
        },
        user: {
            id: String,
            screen_name: String,
        }
    }]
}
```

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- use async/await in your function
- just write `user.screen_name: u`

```
async function remove(guild, u) {
    return await db.updateOne(
        { guild: },
        {
            $pull: {
                feeds: {
                    "user.screen_name": u
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dMW2H2Rmm2h)